# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this4.changeVisibilityFilterModal(true))

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have following code:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Screws',
    title: 'Screws',
    headerRight:
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            this.changeVisibilityFilterModal(true);
        }}>
            <Image style={{marginRight:10}} source={require('../../assets/img/icFilter.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>,
};

changeVisibilityFilterModal(visibility){
    setState({filterModalVisible: visibility});
}
```

The problem is that I cannot access **changeVisibilityFilterModal** within **navigationOptions**. Anyone knows how can I be able to call the method and explain why it does not work as it is currently!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `changeVisibilityFilterModal` directly from the static methods, since it is a `class method`.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerTitle: 'Screws',
    title: 'Screws',
    headerRight:
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            navigation.state.params.visibilityFunc(true);
        }}>
            <Image style={{marginRight:10}} source={require('../../assets/img/icFilter.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>,
})

componentDidMount() {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({ visibilityFunc: this.changeVisibilityFilterModal });
    }

changeVisibilityFilterModal = (visibility) => {
    this.setState({filterModalVisible: visibility});
}
```

Comment: static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    headerTitle: 'Screws',
    title: 'Screws',
    headerRight:
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            navigation.state.params.visibilityFunc(true);
        }}>
            <Image style={{marginRight:10}} source={require('../../assets/img/icFilter.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>,
}; this code return errors, its not properly set

Comment: thanks its working, and thanks for explaining as well!

Answer (score 0):

Change you changeVisibilityFilterModal to :

```
changeVisibilityFilterModal = (visibility) => {
    setState({filterModalVisible: visibility});
}
```

So you don't have to bind this.